# Implementing D3 grouped bar chart with line chart in angular

Tags: angular, d3.js, stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-grouped-bar-chart-11-r2jkny?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchart.ts

Trying to implement grouped bar chart with line chart.
attached the code , but not able to render the line chart.
It fails with error : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x0')

[image]

Added line graph above, but it is unable to read x2 scale everytime.

Comment: A stackblitz is nice but post relevant code here as well.

Comment: are you looking for anything specific? 
this is little bit bigger to post here in question as it is implementing both grouped barplot and line chart 
using 3 axis to plot barplot and then appending line chart to it.